# Why is a function without self argument not visible to other functions in that class?

Tags: python, class, scope, visibility, self

In Python, when I'm defining a function inside a class, I can include `self` as one of the arguments to access the member variables of that class, and I can also choose not include `self` as the argument if I don't need to access its member variables. But then I discovered that if the function does not have `self` as arguments, then it becomes invisible to other functions in that class. For example

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, val:int) -> None:
        self.a = val
    def f(a:int) -> int:
        return a + 1
    def g(self) -> int:
        return f(self.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test(2)
    print(t.g())
```

The above codes will lead to the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/louchenfei/Downloads/lc.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(t.g())
  File "/Users/louchenfei/Downloads/lc.py", line 7, in g
    return f(self.a)
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

I wonder why that's the case and what are the rules for visibilities of functions defined in a class?

Comment: The names of the function's arguments are completely irrelevant; you simply aren't telling Python to find the function in the class.  A plain `f()` looks for the name as a local or global variable; you'd have to write `Test.f()` to look it up in the class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to test your assumptions first before describing the problem. Notice that `return f(self.a)` causes the same `NameError` even if `f` has a `self` argument. The name `self` is **not special**.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to know what you want, but one solution is to make `f` a `staticmethod`. Still you need to have a reference to `Test` in some way:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, val:int) -> None:
        self.a = val
    @staticmethod
    def f(a:int) -> int:
        return a + 1
    def g(self) -> int:
        return self.f(self.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test(2)
    print(t.g())
```

Here, the call is `self.f(self.a)`.

The method `f` is not in scope inside another method.

Comment: I think it's clear what they want: They want to know the rule that says that they have to refer to `f` as `self.f` from `g`.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Its never clear what the OP really wants. They *could* actually need a free function `f`. I'm suggesting using `staticmethod` as possibly the smallest change to get running code.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize `f` is not in scope of other functions and I have to use `Test.f()` or `staticmethod` to access it.

Comment: Yes, in fact, maybe `Test.f()` would be simpler, but it is unconventional to define `f()` as you have it. The conventions are: 1. `f(self)` 2. `@staticmethod` 3. `@classmethod` (probably not useful here)

Comment: You may want to revert edit your question back to edit number 2. I think that is closest to how you were thinking about methods in classes.

Comment: `f` is not in the scope of **any** function. There isn't a separately existing `f`, only an *attribute* `f` of the `Test` class. It is the same as how there is no built-in `upper`, only an attribute of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are just 2 simple things.

1. where you created the g method in the return need to write `self.f(self.a)`
2. the more important in that return statement you are passing to `f(self.a)` but you are not passing a like number `self.a` but you are passing self because where you created the `f()` method you called self with a.
   python doesn't care how you call the instance in the methods declaration but the first argument will be ever the instance.
   only way i know is using `@staticmethod` decorator, or that can be right if your `__init__` returns a integer and in the `g()` return doesn't pass nothing... like
   do this::

```
class Test(int):
    def __init__(self, val:int) -> None:
        self =val

    def f(a:int) -> int:
        return a + 1
    def g(self) -> int:
        return self.f()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test(2)
    print(t.g())

##or declare __add__

class Test:
      def __init__(self, val:int)->None:
            self.a =val
      def f(a:int) -> int:
            return a + 1
      def g(self) -> int:
            return self.f()
      def __add__(self,other):
            return self.a + other
```